# Anderson Valley Bourbon Barrel Stout Recipe

Tags: recipe, stout

I'm newer to home brewing (about 8 batches extract, 1 partial mash) and looking to tackle this. It was absolutely amazing.

Could somebody help me out with the recipe? Is this the right place to ask?

Notes: The stout was very well balanced, with a strong and delayed (about 1 second) aftertaste of vanilla. I have never brewed with vanilla or oats, so please be specific about how to handle that. I'm ok with neglecting the 'Bourbon Barrel' conditioning.

Thanks!

https://avbc.com/our-beers/anderson-valley-wild-turkey-bourbon-barrel-stout/

BITTERNESS:
14 IBU

MALTS:
Pale Two-Row, Crystal (40L & 80L), Roasted Barley, Munich, Chocolate, Oats

HOPS:
Columbus, Northern Brewer

Comment: I'm looking for a partial mash recipe, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this beer many times (I live in Nor Cal) and you picked a hell of a beer to clone.

To get the vanilla I recommend American Oak.  American Oak has larger pores than French oak and it will transmit the flavors more quickly.  Light or Medium toast will work.  Take the oak cubes or chips and soak them in your favorite Bourbon for a week.  Then put the whole thing into your carboy in secondary.  That is where the vanilla will come from.

As far as Oats, flaked oats can go in with the rest of your grains.  raw oats need to boil for an hour to gelatinize.

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like my next project is all ready to go! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a clone recipe online, and have never tasted the beer.  I would guess that some or all of the vanilla flavor came from aging on oak. I would try light toasted French Oak cubes as part of the recipe.  I have heard that cloning a beer can take many, many attempts to get right, but you have a ton of information to start.  Personally, I would start by trying to contact the brewer and see if they can give you some tips.